# Pass arguments to Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

This is my script:

```
workflow Run-RemoteScript {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)][string[]]$Targets,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=1)][PSCredential]$Credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=1)][String]$Path
    )
    foreach -parallel ($Target in $Targets) {
        parallel {
            "Executing on: $Target"
            InlineScript {
                Invoke-Command -FilePath $using:Path -ComputerName $using:Target -Credential $using:Credentials 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This workflow is nested to a function. How do I pass the parameters from my top-level function to the `Invoke-Command`? Inside the `InlineScript{}`? `$using:MyVar` does not seem to work.

Comment: Side-note: both `Credentials` and `$Path` parameters are on Position=1

Comment: @Theo Thanks for pointing that out, I missed that!

Comment: I'd question using a workflow for this when Invoke-Command can take an array of computer names.

Comment: @RichardSiddaway Would using just an array allow parallel execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the help for Invoke-Command. There are a couple of ways to do this without the additional complication of a workflow.  Look at -ThrottleLimit or -InDisconnectedSession parameters for instance. Example 16 is of possible relevance

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Example 16 is definitely of relevance to the script I'm creating. Is it possible to get the output of the script that has been run on a remote computer?